# Given a differentiable function for every $x \geq 0$, define a differentiable function for every $x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given $f(x)$:

- $f(0)=1$
- Positive for every $x \geq 0$
- Differentiable for every $x \geq 0$

Let $g(x)=
 \begin{cases}
  f(x)    & \text{$x \geq 0$}\\
  1/f(-x) & \text{$x \leq 0$}
 \end{cases}
$

Is $g(x)$ differentiable for every $x$?

I believe that the answer is yes, because the only questionable point is at $x=0$.

And since $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0^-}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to 0^+}{g(x)} = 1}$, function $g(x)$ is differentiable  at that point.

For $x>0$, function $g(x)$ is differentiable because function $f(x)$ is differentiable.

For $x<0$, function $g(x)$ is differentiable because function $1/f(-x)$ is differentiable.

Is this correct, or am I missing something (a counterexample would be appreciated in this case)?

Comment: Let $f(x) = 1$ if $x = 0$ and $2$ otherwise. Then your $g$ is not differentiable at the origin, but is everywhere else. In general you're not going to be able to get away with anything less than right-differentiability at the origin on $f$.

Comment: You've shown $g$ is *continuous* at zero. Why is it differentiable?

Comment: @JulienClancy You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Julien Clancy: In your example, $f(x)$ is **not** differentiable (as defined in my question).

Comment: @Julien Clancy: OK, I see the problem now, it works if $f(x)$ is differentiable for every $x \geq 0$ (not only for every $x>0$). Thanks.

Comment: You have a problem for $x\lt 0$ as we have no information about $f$

Comment: @ellya: I did not define $f(x)$ for $x<0$ because it is not relevant to the question. I am looking to construct a differentiable function for every $x$, using the above definition for $f(x)$.

Comment: In the definition of $g$, do you mean $g(x) = 1/f(-x)$ when $x\le0$?

Comment: @Greg Martin: Yep, my mistake; thanks. Will revise the question.

Answer (score 3):

You're correct that the only point where differentiability is an issue is $x=0$. But as user7530 pointed out, the sentence you wrote that ends "$g(x)$ is differentiably at the point" is actually a proof of continuity, not differentiability.

The limit you need to consider is $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{g(0+h)-g(0)}h = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{g(h)-1}h$. Since $g$ is defined differently on either side of $x=0$, you'll need to consider left- and right-hand limits separately. For the left-hand limit, you might want to reread the proof of the quotient rule for inspiration.

Finally, you write that the function $f$, which is defined only for $x\ge0$, is differentiable for $x\ge0$. In particular, what do you mean to say $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$? Do you mean the one-sided variant of the difference-quotient limit exists there? Does, for example, $f(x)=1+\sqrt x$ qualify?

EDITED TO ADD: No matter how $f(x)=1+\sqrt x$ is extended to the region $x<0$, it will not be differentiable at $x=0$. This is because
$$
\lim_{h\to0+} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}h = \lim_{h\to0+} \frac{1+\sqrt h-1}h = \lim_{h\to0+} \frac1{\sqrt h} = \infty.
$$

Comment: Thank you @Greg Martin. Yes, $f(x)=1+\sqrt x$ qualifies. But I expect the $g(x)$ solution to be correct for **every** $f(x)$. If there exists an $f(x)$ for which it doesn't work, then I want an example (counterexample for my assumption).

Comment: $f(x)=1+\sqrt x$ does yield a counterexample - not because the two halves of the graph don't meet smoothly, but because the tangent line is vertical at $x=0$, so technically the derivative does not exist there.

Comment: Are you sure? If yes, can you please explain it in details (in the answer above)? Thanks.